# nohup command on Jenkins silently exiting

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a Jenkins pipeline in which I'm trying to run the following command to deploy a jar on the server.

```
steps{
    sh 'nohup java -jar admin/target/*.jar'
}
```

The actual code I'm using is this one.

```
String deployApplication = "BUILD_ID=dontKillMe " + "nohup java -jar " + dir_name + "/target/*.jar &"
```

But I'm unable to do so as this command is getting silently ingored when running through Jenkins. But when I run the same command manually through the terminal it runs successfully. And I tried the pwd command using Jenkins, it also ran successfully.

I have tried the fixes suggested by different people like the "BUILD_ID=dontKillMe" and "JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe" but it did not work for me.

```
String deployApplication = "BUILD_ID=dontKillMe " + "nohup java -jar admin/target/*.jar"
String deployApplication = "JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe " + "nohup java -jar admin/target/*.jar"
```

I tried using the above method by saving it in a variable, but it did not work. Please suggest what is going wrong?
P.S. I'm also attaching the manual execution output. The file in which these commands are getting saved in commands.sh and the port I'm using is 8100. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCsFU.png)

Comment: Try putting an ampersand at end of the sh script and then execute it. I mean, use `nohup java -jar admin/target/yourjar.jar &`

Comment: Actually I have & at the end, I did not put the question. I'm using this command 
```String deployApplication = "BUILD_ID=dontKillMe " + "nohup java -jar " + dir_name + "/target/*.jar &"```
I will add it in the edited version

Comment: Are you sure that you are executing the command from the intended directory on the server end? If the relative path of the Jar is incorrect, then also the command can silently fail.

Comment: Yes I think the directory is correct because I have printed the pwd above this command, and it is same as the intended directory.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a lot of reasons why the script may be failing at the server end when you are trying to deploy:

1. Make sure that you are in the intended directory and logged in as the intended user with right permission while trying to execute the script. Try to see if a tail on nohup.out gives you any lead on what could be wrong.
2. If you have the exact jar name and it is a single jar, can you try to keep the exact name in script? Also see whether there is another application or another instance of the same application occupying the port which is intended to be used (assuming the jar is a runnable jar similar to what you get for springboot based applications). Use `netstat -tunlp | grep portnumber`.
3. If no process is running, then it may be a firewall issue. Check if firewall rules are written properly to enable the port at the server end. You can simply disable the firewall temporarily and then check if the command is executed successfully. Use `systemctl stop firewalld` to stop the firewall.